# Android hasn't references on some assemblies in constructed assembly in project\obj\debug folder

Tags: android, reference, xamarin

Why android hasn't references on some assemblies in constructed assembly in `project\obj\debug` folder?
In bin folder assembly has all needed references.
To see references I used dotPeek application.